# Basic JQuery: Replace a link string with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

How do I change:

http://test.dev/event?event=94&page=4

to

http://test.dev/contest?contest=94&page=4

using Jquery?

I have the following code and would like to change it in the event of a right click: (CASE 2)

```
// will_paginate + ajax 
// updates two divs: #pages and #pagelink
// see places#search controller; passes 4 parameters to the search action

$(function(){
  $('.pagination a').mousedown(function(event) {
      switch (event.which) {
          case 1:
              $(".pagination a").live("click", function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();

              // Javascript Regular expression function; extracts page number from full url
              var extractPageNumber = function(s) {
                var r=/page=(\d+)/, m=(""+s).match(r);
                return (m) ? Number(m[1]) : undefined;
              };
              var pageregex = extractPageNumber($(this).attr('href'));
              $(".pagination").html("Page is loading...")
              $.get("/event", {  event: $("input[name=event]").val(), page: pageregex }, function(data) {
                $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
                console.log(data.page_link);
                $('#tweets').html(data.html);
                });
              return false;
              });
          break;

          case 2:
                break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Is a simple "event"->"contest" string replacement acceptable? And also, what happens if someone normally clicks the link (as opposed to right-clicking it)?

Comment: In the event of a normal click, it uses JQuery to GET a JSON element from the server. It updates the page element from JSON using the $('#tweets').html(data.html). The right click is used to get another URL that does not return JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
...
case 2:
   var href = $(this).attr("href").replace(/event/g, "contest")
   // do stuff with href
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://test.dev/event?event=94&page=4".replace(/event/g,'contest');
```